# Get last 30 days order with timestamp

Tags: mysql

```
Table Orders
order_id
timestamp

Table OrderLines
orderlines_id
order_id
```

Sample data

Order table

```
order_id tmestamp 
       1 2017-01-10 17:47:25
       2 2017-01-21 17:53:39
       3 2017-01-21 17:55:04
       4 2017-01-21 18:16:30 
       5 2016-12-21 18:17:12
```

Sample data orderline table

```
orderlines_id order_id
            1        1
            2        2
            3        3
            4        4
            5        5
```

I would like to see orders for the `last` 30 days from today's date and current time. I am not sure if my query is working correctly.

Approach 1:

```
SELECT 
o.timestamp
,ol.retail_price
FROM orders o,
mpos.orderlines ol
where o.timestamp between now() - INTERVAL 30 day and now()
group by o.order_id;
```

Based on the sample data below, it only returns one record where as it should return more than one.

```
2017-01-10 17:47:25
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT 
o.timestamp
,ol.retail_price
FROM orders o,
mpos.orderlines ol
where o.order_id = ol.order_id
AND ol.order_status_id = 1
AND now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

This query returns me more rows but also data that goes more than 30 days prior to todays date and time. Please see below

result:

```
   2017-01-10 17:47:25
   2017-01-21 17:53:39
   2017-01-21 17:55:04
   2017-01-21 18:16:30 
   2016-12-21 18:17:12
```

Comment: Presumably there are no orders in the future?

Comment: funny, but i was referring to last 30days :P

Comment: It's not intended as a joke. It's just question.

Comment: And, today being **2017**-02-20, there are no rows that satisfy the condition.

Comment: so based on the data above and the query i posted, it's correct?

Comment: You appear to be interested in results greater than the current date minus 30 days. That's all.

Comment: ahh i understand now, no sorry. I am interested in the opposite.

Comment: Not according to your question.

Comment: "Get last 30 days order with timestamp" ? im a little confused

Comment: You and me both. I think you're making this problem unnecessarily complicated by 1) including within your sample data set dates from over a year ago 2) providing orderlines and orders that share the same id numbers. Let's try again. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: hmm yea you're right, I will update this question again.

Comment: @Strawberry I have revised the question, please check

Comment: I can only refer you to my previous comment

Answer (score 2):

Get last 30 days orders

```
SELECT o.`timestamp`, ol.retail_price
FROM orders AS o
JOIN mpos.orderlines AS ol ON o.order_id = ol.order_id
WHERE ol.order_status_id = 1
AND datediff(now(), o.`timestamp`) < 30
```

Comment: thanks, is this not the same as what I am doing? by the looks based on this, the query i wrote produces the same result

Answer (score -1):

That's because in the second approach you are not checking if the timestamp is in a range of time...

Try this and see if it gives you the same result

```
SELECT 
o.timestamp
,ol.retail_price
FROM orders o,
mpos.orderlines ol
where o.order_id = ol.order_id
AND ol.order_status_id = 1
AND ol.timestamp between now() and now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Comment: `SELECT 2 BETWEEN 3 AND 1`